# Preventing a form post submit download from cancelling Ajax actions

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, download

I have a button **[Download Document]** which does these two things:

1. Makes an ajax call and populates a table with data.
2. `Post` submits a form which:

   a. Runs a back-end script that creates a document

   b. Returns the document to the browser in a way that the browser downloads the document.

One problem. The `post` submit is not ajax, which means that the browser treats it the same way as clicking on a link, refreshing a page, or closing the window, **e.g. it cancels the ajax request without even getting a response error**.

Using `.preventDefault()` on the button doesn't work. It does allow the ajax call (**1**)  to complete successfully, but then the form isn't submitted, so (**2**) the form is never submitted.

```
    <form action="/backendScript" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Download Document">
    </form>

    $(".downloadBtn").on("click", function (e) {
        generateTable();
        e.preventDefault(); // without this, the ajax in generateTable(); is cancelled, but with it, the form isn't submitted.
    });
```

Doing (**2**) with an ajax `post` also doesn't work. It can complete (**2.a**), but the returned document goes straight to Javascript, instead of the browser, and Javascript isn't able to cause a download event, so (**2.b**) fails with this approach.

```
   $.post("/backendScript", formData, function (generatedDoc) {
        console.log(generatedDoc); //yay, here's our doc! but how do we download it??
    });
```

So it looks like I *must* `post` submit the form. But how can I prevent this from canceling any ajax requests that are in progress?

Comment: You should add the form attribute target="_blank".  This way the download can start immediately and the ajax calls are not cancelled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the success/error/whatever response event you want from your ajax call in `generateTable`, submit the form.  Either `document.forms["myform"].submit();` or `$('#myform').submit();` (depending on if you want to use vanilla js or jQuery).

Comment: Nice. The one down side of this is that the table being populated might be large and the user will have to wait for the download to begin, but I suppose that's an acceptable trade off. Why does `preventDefault()` need to be moved before the ajax?

Comment: I just like that being the first thing.  Basically it's my code saying, "Hey, I'll take it from here."  Just feels better doing it first.

Comment: You are right though, it doesn't matter.  I removed that as it isn't relevant.